# How do I create system integration tests using Firebase and Swift/Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I want to create tests for user account creation, so I can confirm my app is uploading the correct data, but I'm struggling to find the right way to do it. So far I've been unsuccessful in writing a test that works. This error prevents me from getting any further:

`caught error: "An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered"`

I've not written tests in Xcode before, and I've had lots of trouble finding guides on this sort of issue. Here is my test code:

```swift
import XCTest
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import SwiftUI
@testable import Baseline

class AccountTests: XCTestCase {
    var baselineApp: BaselineApp!

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        baselineApp = BaselineApp()
    }

    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        async {
            let idString = baselineApp.authenticationState.loggedInUser?.uid
            if let idString = idString {
                try await baselineApp.authenticationState.deleteUser(id: idString)
            }
            baselineApp.authenticationState.signout()
        }
    }

    func testAccountCreation() async throws {
        let firstName = "Test"
        let lastName = "Xcode"
        let email = "testdummy5684+XCtest@gmail.com"
        let password = "testingForXcode1234"
        let gender = UserDocument.Gender.male
        let birthdate = Timestamp(date: Date())
        let suggestedRank = 0
        let image = UIImage(named: "social")?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        try await baselineApp.authenticationState.signupNewUser(email: email, password: password, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, gender: gender, jpegImageData: image, suggestedRank: suggestedRank, birthdate: birthdate)
        let foundUserResult = baselineApp.authenticationState.loggedInUser
        let foundUserDocumentResult = baselineApp.authenticationState.loggedInUserDocument
        let foundUser = try XCTUnwrap(foundUserResult)
        let foundUserDocument = try XCTUnwrap(foundUserDocumentResult)
        XCTAssertNotNil(foundUserDocument, "Failed to get user document")
        XCTAssertEqual(firstName, foundUserDocument.firstName, "Tried \(firstName), but got \(foundUserDocument.firstName)")
    }
}
```

I'm creating an instance of my app where my @main is, because I have observable objects instantiated there, alongside Firebase's config settings. I have keychain sharing enabled, and my app works otherwise (like logging into a pre-existing account).

I'm running Xcode 13.0 beta (13A5155e) and targeting iOS 15.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, also lack of docs/examples on using Firebase in XCTest in general. Did you find a solution? `An error occurred when accessing the keychain. The NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey field in the NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain more information about the error encountered`